# How to set permission in a particular BigQuery dataset to run query and create table?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to restrict users to see only a particular dataset in BigQuery. I want users to only be able to run queries and create tables. So I share the dataset permission and gave them role BigQuery Data Viewer (to view data) and BigQuery User (to run queries and create table). But whenever I run a query I'm getting the following error:

Access Denied: Project xxx: User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project xxx.

I checked the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control) and BigQuery User role should have bigquery.jobs.create permission. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to `Granting roles to a service account for specific resources` [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts), where you can find 5 steps to accomplish your goal by using  `IAM & Admin` page.

You can also use command line for create a new service account and grant permissions to it:

Create new service account:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts create <NAME>
```

Grant the permissions:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <YOUR_PROJECT_ID> --member "serviceAccount:<NAME>@<YOUR_PROJECT_ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com" --role "roles/bigquery.jobUser"
```

Also, check with this command that you granted the permissions to the service account:

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy <YOUR_PROJECT_ID>
```

Let me know about the results. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The description for `BigQuery User` in `Share Dataset` says:

> When applied to a project, access to run queries, create data sets, read data set metadata and list tables. **When applied to a data set, access to read data set metadata and list tables within the data set.**

So you need to assign `BigQuery Job User` to the account at a project level.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same use case which is turning out to be surprisingly complex to setup correctly for what I assumed would be a fairly common scenario. We wish to configure a project for BigQuery adhoc usage which would be granted as needed to internal power users.

With our configuration we want to allow users to only see their own dataset but want them to have full control within their dataset. As a BQ admin, I can create a dataset for them and then assign them the BigQuery Data Editor role within the Dataset directly but two problems still remain.

- The user cannot upload files larger than 10MB, so they must be granted permissions on a cloud storage bucket to upload their files to and then import to BQ.
- More importantly the user cannot create a table from any source that is not another BQ table!! This is because the bigquery.jobs.create permission must be granted at the *project level*.

In the end, in order to hit our use case requirements and a decent UX, we needed to do three things.

- Create a BQ dataset for the user and grant them BigQuery Data Editor permissions on the Dataset.
- Create a GCS Bucket for the user and grant them Cloud Storage Object Admin permissions on the bucket.
- Create a new custom project IAM role and assign to the end user which we called "BigQuery Adhoc User" and granted the following permissions:

  bigquery.jobs.create
  bigquery.jobs.get
  bigquery.jobs.list
  storage.buckets.list

This in turn gave us the UX and data security we were looking for where users only have access to their own data, but are still contained in one project. The fact that a user **needs** an IAM role at the project level just to create a table from GCS or direct upload seems like bad design.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue (where I wanted to add permissions to a specific data set allowing the person to query and export data but not to view anything else) and it worked when I added the Roles: **BigQuery Job User & BigQuery Resource Viewer** on a project level. Those were the only roles that contained the following permissions needed:

```
bigquery.jobs.create
bigquery.jobs.get
bigquery.jobs.list
```

Please note that I didn't need a person to be able to upload anything and to store it.

Follow up question: Is there a better way to grant the listed access than signing the Roles I listed?

Thank you in advance!